# Negative look ahead matching when it should not match

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I made this regex to match var being read

```
\bvar\b([^;^{]*?([\s]*?([<]|[>]|[!]|[=]{2})))([^;]*?)(?!=)
```

These are my test strings:

```
var->var1 = blah;     //must not match -but matches
var = 8;              //as expected - do not match          
if(var >= 9)          //as expected - matches
if(var ->var1 == balh) //as expected - matches
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/17cqdA/1/)

(`([<]|[>]|[!]|[=]{2})` checks for the presence of >,<,! or ==)

My issue is that it should match (no need to get the result) when var is read, not written. But when
`var->` comes in my test string, it automatically matches because of `[>]`
in my regex. I tried negative lookahead `([^;]*?)(?!=)` .But this does not do anything to my original regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the current expression using

```py
\bvar\b(?!->)(?=[^;^{]*(?:[<>!]|==))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2pKyWb/5).

*Details*:

- `\bvar\b`  - a whole word `var`
- `(?!->)` - `->` immediately to the right of the current location is not allowed
- `(?=[^;^{]*(?:[<>!]|==))` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be any zero or more chars other than `;`, `^`, and `{` and then `<`, `>`, `!`, or `==`.

Comment: with a small change of adding two =, this works for most cases 
 \bvar\b(?!->)(?=[^;^{]*([<>!]|[=]{2})). But when multiple -> is present, this would not work like this-  https://regex101.com/r/2pKyWb/3

Comment: @Aparnavenugopal Sorry, I misread the comments on what should get matched. Fixed the positive lookahead as ``(?=[^;^{]*(?:[<>!]|==))``.

Comment: @ WiktorStribiżew , when you added the non capturing group, it for some reason matches only if you have one space after var if followed by -> . Today I learned about the non-capturing groups, thankyou.

Comment: Do you want to say `if(var->var1 == blah)` must match?

Comment: @Aparnavenugopal Try a completely revamped pattern, `\bvar\b(?!.*(?<![><=])=(?!=))(?=(?:\s*->\s*\w+)*\s*(?:[<!]|-?>|={2}))`, see https://regex101.com/r/2pKyWb/6

Comment: As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/2pKyWb/7), that does not work, and it looks a lot complex that I can't figure out what's not working. But why is the last regex not matching the whitespace? I checked by removing `(?!->)` in your original answer, which is causing the whitespace matching problem. Any idea why?

Comment: @Aparnavenugopal That was a wrong approach. So, you say you do not expect your matches to flow across lines? Replace `\s` with the literal space, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2pKyWb/8).

Comment: Thank you, with some modifications, I was able to obtain what I [needed](https://regex101.com/r/2pKyWb/9). Regarding your last comment, the lazy quantifier for \s will work instead of literal space.